# salesforce how to change a component from non-global to global

Tags: visualforce-component

I want to look at and modify the code of component in  salesforce. But when I open that component it is showing this message "Component is not global" and I cannot view the code as nothing is displayed beyond that. I am logged into production. Can anyone tell me how can I access the code of this component so that I can start modifying according to my requirement. Is this a permission issue ?
Please bear with me as I pretty new to salesforce. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you see a blue install symbol before the component (Guessing you are looking at a managed package component?) As per this doc : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_packaging_intro.htm  When a package with a non-global component is installed, users that view the component in Setup see “Component is not global” instead of the content of the component. In addition, the component is not included in the component reference.

Comment: Yes I can see a blue install symbol. So this means I cannot view the component content ? Or there still some way to view it . Thanks

Comment: Nope, it means that you are looking at a managed package component and the vendor of the package has locked access to the code and attributes of the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see a blue install symbol before the component (Guessing you are looking at a managed package component?) As per this doc :

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_packaging_intro.htm

When a package with a non-global component is installed, users that view the component in Setup see “Component is not global” instead of the content of the component. In addition, the component is not included in the component reference.